# What is the proper way to use npm jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

What is the proper way to use npm jquery-ui, please?
I am trying to do

```
npm install --save-dev jquery
npm install --save-dev jquery-ui
```

then in .js file I wrote

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('jquery-ui');

$(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

but it needs jQuery to be a global object, so I tried

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery');
require('jquery-ui');

$(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

but it still now working, it returns "datepicker is not a function".
I am sure that I have no other jQuery on my page or code.
What works is

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery');
require('node_modules/jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker');

$(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

So I wonder, what is the proper way.
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Looking at the code it seems like it's only got an AMD loader, if your using webpack it will handle both common.js & AMD anyway.  So I think you can do define(['jquery','jquery-ui] , function ($) {  . I'm not an AMD fan, so that bit might be wrong.

Comment: from where does your  require function comes out? Are you using browserify, webpack, requireJS... ?

Comment: I understand obviously something wrong, I believed that require() is function from node.js. I use Browserify.